# Flags game based on Google Maps stopped working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with my site Guesstheflag.com. The site is based on a game in which people need to guess which flags belong to which countries. The site uses Google Maps to show the countries on a map.

I bought the site two years ago from someone who developed the game. Unfortunately I am not a developer and I have little knowledge of building websites. All went well the past two years and I never had problems, but since a few days if you go to the site you get a white screen in the game screen (in all browsers). I can't reach the developer of the game and I tried to find a solution myself but I don't know what I'm doing exactly so that's quite hard. ;)

Has there been a recent change in the Google Maps API (I couldn't find that) and is there a simple solution? If not, is there someone here who could help me fix the problem for a small fee?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is a general programming q/a site. If you are looking for hiring a developer, you should try on dedicated web site.

Comment: @Steve B Thanks, any tips on a good website for that? I used several freelance websites in the past (freelance.com, odesk.com) but have not found good developers there. I thought, maybe there is a simple solution or if not someone that can help for a fee...that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Google Maps JavaScript API just advanced a minor version increment to 3.9[<sup>changelog</sup>](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog) and the default version advanced from 3.6 to 3.7. A few others have run into problems. Info about which version you should use is available in the [**Versioning** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning).

The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 docs to start with are:

- The [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq)
- The [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)
- The [API Reference Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)
- The [Example Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)

Comment: Thanks Sean. I found I have version 2: http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAABIkYkHiHRcnlQrLmORXiBhRWz7Ank4u8tfDUvJSVpzvLCS_n1xQU-DX7K6M7O2-pXiuOWLHMx7ACrg&amp;hl=us. I can't find in the documentation how I need to update to version 3.9 (latest). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Added links to my original answer to point you toward where you want to start getting more info about the v3 API.